# Eslint rule/Vscode setting to prevent importing folders without index

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, tsc

### Question:

Is there an ESLint rule to enforce usage of `*/index` on imports.

### Example:

File structure:

```
utils/
   - index.js
   - a.js
   - b.js

main.js
```

main.js

```js
// WRONG
import utils from "./utils";

// OK 
import utils from "./utils/index";
```

### Why

I need this because my project is using `tscpaths` to replace absolute paths with relative paths after typescript compilation, but, for some reason, it doesn't replace when the `*/index` is not present.

### Alternative

If the rule doesn't exist, is there a vscode setting that would automatically add the `index` in auto imports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1, restructure your project so there are no `index.js` to import. The historic reason it is called `index` was to contain an index of the contents of that folder, to gather the typically exported things in a neat package so people don't have to look at the details within the folder. If that isn't what you need **just don't call it `index`.** You can probably just rename them all to `main.js`, mass find-replace the imports and future auto-imports from your IDE will work.

Option 2, If there aren't too many folders where this is an issue you can write a config for [`no-internal-imports`](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-internal-modules.md) rule such that importing a folder by name is considered an "internal reference". This is probably the worst solution since there is no auto-fix and adding new folders requires updating the eslint config but this might be helpful to mention as an option

Option 3, create a modified version of the [`no-useless-path-segments` rule](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/src/rules/no-useless-path-segments.js#L95) that does this, it currently has the opposite logic as you want so you would modify the code around lines 95-108 to check if the import isn't an index import but resolves to one suggest the fix:

```
// assuming your rule has an option called enforceIndex
if (options && options.enforceIndex && !regexUnnecessaryIndex.test(importPath)) {
    // if the import path is not pointing to an index file check if it resolves to a path that looks like an index file
    const resolved_path = resolve(importPath, context);
    if(regexUnnecessaryIndex.test(resolved_path)){
        // if the resolved_path resolves to something that looks like an index then suggest adding /index
        return reportWithProposedPath(`${importPath}/index`);
    }
}
```

But the fact that there is an eslint rule that *imposes the exact opposite logic you want* should be a decent indicator that what you are asking for is not exactly considered good form.